How do i insert a value into a chart?
So i have this code that makes a bar chart that would shows a teaching points an university has. But, when i try to choose a university, the value of teaching1, 2 and 3 would just sit empty. Heres the HTML:
<th width="300px">
            <select class="form-control" id="select1" onchange="item1(this.value)">
              <option value="0">-- Select Anyone --</option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th width="300px">
            <select class="form-control" id="select2" onchange="item2(this.value)">
              <option value="0">-- Select Anyone --</option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th width="300px">
            <select class="form-control" id="select3" onchange="item3(this.value)">
              <option value="0">-- Select Anyone --</option>
            </select>
          </th>

 <tr>
          <th>Teaching</th>
          <td id="teaching1">N/A</td>
          <td id="teaching2">N/A</td>
          <td id="teaching3">N/A</td>
        </tr>
  

Javascript:
var ctxTeaching = document.getElementById('chartTeaching').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctxTeaching, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['University 1', 'University 2', 'University 3'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Teaching',
      data: [
        document.getElementById("teaching1").innerHTML,
        document.getElementById("teaching2").innerHTML,
        document.getElementById("teaching3").innerHTML
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});

i tried using ais and stuff but i just still cant get a clue of whats wrong with the code
Before i use the new code, i did this and it works just fine. But, it will shows all the Unviersities from the JS file
var ctxTeaching = document.getElementById('chartTeaching').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctxTeaching, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: teachingValues.map((_, i) => `University ${i + 1}`),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Teaching',
      data: teachingValues,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});


Try making a runnable example, you can use jsFiddle, codepen or a similar service, or even better the stackoverflow inline snippet. As it is now, your post doesn't contain enough information for us to debug - we don't know how your data is structured, what the actual options  are and what do the functions item1, item2, item3 do.

It seems that when you select a university the teaching values are not being updated in your chart dataset. For this, you need separate functions to handle each dropdown change.
Refer the code below for reference:


function item1(value) {
  document.getElementById('teaching1').innerHTML = value; // Update the HTML with selected value
  updateChart(); // Update the chart 
}

function item2(value) {
  document.getElementById('teaching2').innerHTML = value;
  updateChart();
}

function item3(value) {
  document.getElementById('teaching3').innerHTML = value;
  updateChart();
}

function updateChart() {  // Function to fetch the updated data
  const data = [
    document.getElementById("teaching1").innerHTML,
    document.getElementById("teaching2").innerHTML,
    document.getElementById("teaching3").innerHTML
  ];
  chartTeaching.data.datasets[0].data = data;
  chartTeaching.update();
}


window.onload = function() { // Initialize data in window onload
            const ctxTeaching = document.getElementById('chartTeaching').getContext('2d');
            window.chartTeaching = new Chart(ctxTeaching, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['University 1', 'University 2', 'University 3'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Teaching',
                        data: [0, 0, 0], 
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
              }
          }
       }
   });
}
.form-control {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 5px 0;           
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>University Teaching Points</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="300px">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select1" onchange="item1(this.value)">
                        <option value="0">-- Select Anyone --</option>
                        <option value="10">University 1 - 10</option>
                        <option value="20">University 2 - 20</option>
                        <option value="30">University 3 - 30</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th width="300px">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select2" onchange="item2(this.value)">
                        <option value="0">-- Select Anyone --</option>
                        <option value="10">University 1 - 10</option>
                        <option value="20">University 2 - 20</option>
                        <option value="30">University 3 - 30</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
                <th width="300px">
                    <select class="form-control" id="select3" onchange="item3(this.value)">
                        <option value="0">-- Select Anyone --</option>
                        <option value="10">University 1 - 10</option>
                        <option value="20">University 2 - 20</option>
                        <option value="30">University 3 - 30</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Teaching</th>
                <td id="teaching1">0</td>
                <td id="teaching2">0</td>
                <td id="teaching3">0</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <canvas id="chartTeaching" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
</html>



